# React JS Parent Child Component Events Sharing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Below are my react components, Here I am trying to create Parent component which is responsible for getting keyboard event 'keyPressed' and whichever key is pressed it should remove a matching child  component from view.

Your help and suggestions are appreciated.

**PARENT COMPONENT**
This component is responsible for creating characters (a-z, A-Z) array and create a board to display each character as a child named ball component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Ball from "./Ball";

export default class Board extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      letters: []
    };
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind(this);
    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    let letters = [];

    // small a - z
    for (let i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
      letters.push({ letter: String.fromCharCode(i), code: i });
    }

    // capital A - Z
    for (let i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
      letters.push({ letter: String.fromCharCode(i), code: i });
    }

    this.setState(state => ({
      letters: self.shuffle(letters)
    }));
  }

  shuffle(arr) {
    var ctr = arr.length,
      temp,
      index;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (ctr > 0) {
      // Pick a random index
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
      // Decrease ctr by 1
      ctr--;
      // And swap the last element with it
      temp = arr[ctr];
      arr[ctr] = arr[index];
      arr[index] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  handleEvent(e) {
    const k = e.charCode;
    // HELP NEEDED HERE
    // Need to find matching children component of Ball to trigger its own setVisibility method.
  }

  render() {
    let ball = this.state.letters.map(item => {
      return <Ball key={item.code} properties={item} bouncing={true} />;
    });

    return (
      <div
        className="overlay-full game"
        onKeyPress={event => this.handleEvent(event)}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        <div className="bubble-wrapper">{ball}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**
every Ball component should have its own state for visibility if its state is visible than only it will render on-screen otherwise it should do nothing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Ball extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRandomSize = this.getRandomSize.bind(this);
    this.getRandomColor = this.getRandomColor.bind(this);
    this.setVisibility = this.setVisibility.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isVisible: true,
      code: this.props.properties.code,
      letter: this.props.properties.letter
    };

    this.ballRef = null;
    this.setBallRef = element => {
      this.ballRef = element;
    };
  }
  getRandomSize() {
    const sizes = ["size-1", "size-2", "size-3", "size-4"];
    return sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  }
  getRandomColor() {
    const colors = [
      "#55efc4",
      "#81ecec",
      "#74b9ff",
      "#a29bfe",
      "#00b894",
      "#00cec9",
      "#0984e3",
      "#6c5ce7",
      "#ffeaa7",
      "#fab1a0",
      "#ff7675",
      "#fd79a8",
      "#fdcb6e",
      "#e17055",
      "#d63031"
    ];
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  setVisibility(key) {
    if (this.state.code === key) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        isVisible: false
      }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { code, letter } = this.state;
    const isBouncing = this.props.bouncing ? "bouncing" : "";
    const isVisible = this.state.isVisible;
    const size = this.getRandomSize();
    const inlineStyle = {
      backgroundColor: this.getRandomColor()
    };

    if (isVisible) {
      return (
        <div
          className={`ball-${code} ${size} ${isBouncing}`}
          style={inlineStyle}
          ref={this.setBallRef}
        >
          {letter}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you cant control child component's method from parent rather you would have to lift the state up to parent and then pass it to your child, so in your case isVisible need to be moved up and then set its state in parent and once it changes it will force re-render of child component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did move visible state to the Parent component and React smartly renders child whenever a state of parent is updated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use Redux for this kind of problem so that you should not struck in the middle of managing states all over your application.

But in case you need to go with the current scenario then you need to make use of refs. React provides [CreateRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
api. Using this you can get the reference to your Ball component and triggers it's setVisibility method. But before that you need to lift up the state for a respective Ball component to the parent component by providing callback function.

Comment: will definitely try this approach too. looks more logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry im pretty knew to the whole programming thing, so my suggestions might not be the best.

```
for (i in letters) { 
if (ball == letters[i]) 
{
ball.setvisibility = false;
}
}
```